# yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: python, yaml, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train KPCONV with SemanticKitti dataset in Google Colab. The code is from here : https://github.com/HuguesTHOMAS/KPConv-PyTorch.

However, this is my output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/KPConv-PyTorch/train_SemanticKitti.py", line 263, in <module>
    balance_classes=True)
  File "/content/KPConv-PyTorch/datasets/SemanticKitti.py", line 103, in __init__
    doc = yaml.safe_load(stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 94, in safe_load
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 72, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 35, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 58, in compose_document
    self.get_event()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 118, in get_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 193, in parse_document_end
    token = self.peek_token()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 128, in peek_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 220, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_value()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 576, in fetch_value
  self.get_mark())
  yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "/content/Data/SemanticKitti/semantic-kitti.yaml", line 26, column 66
```

I have installed PyYAML using pip.
Here is my .yaml file:

```
labels: 
  0 : "unlabeled"
  1 : "outlier"
  10: "car"
  11: "bicycle"
  13: "bus"
  15: "motorcycle"
  16: "on-rails"
  18: "truck"
  20: "other-vehicle"
  30: "person"
  31: "bicyclist"
  32: "motorcyclist"
  40: "road"
  44: "parking"
  48: "sidewalk"
  49: "other-ground"
  50: "building"
  51: "fence"
  52: "other-structure"
  60: "lane-marking"
  70: "vegetation"
  71: "trunk"
  72: "terrain"
  80: "pole"
  81: "traffic-sign"
  99: "other-object"
  252: "moving-car"
  253: "moving-bicyclist"
  254: "moving-person"
  255: "moving-motorcyclist"
  256: "moving-on-rails"
  257: "moving-bus"
  258: "moving-truck"
  259: "moving-other-vehicle"
color_map: # bgr
  0 : [0, 0, 0]
  1 : [0, 0, 255]
  10: [245, 150, 100]
  11: [245, 230, 100]
  13: [250, 80, 100]
  15: [150, 60, 30]
  16: [255, 0, 0]
  18: [180, 30, 80]
  20: [255, 0, 0]
  30: [30, 30, 255]
  31: [200, 40, 255]
  32: [90, 30, 150]
  40: [255, 0, 255]
  44: [255, 150, 255]
  48: [75, 0, 75]
  49: [75, 0, 175]
  50: [0, 200, 255]
  51: [50, 120, 255]
  52: [0, 150, 255]
  60: [170, 255, 150]
  70: [0, 175, 0]
  71: [0, 60, 135]
  72: [80, 240, 150]
  80: [150, 240, 255]
  81: [0, 0, 255]
  99: [255, 255, 50]
  252: [245, 150, 100]
  256: [255, 0, 0]
  253: [200, 40, 255]
  254: [30, 30, 255]
  255: [90, 30, 150]
  257: [250, 80, 100]
  258: [180, 30, 80]
  259: [255, 0, 0]
content: # as a ratio with the total number of points
  0: 0.018889854628292943
  1: 0.0002937197336781505
  10: 0.040818519255974316
  11: 0.00016609538710764618
  13: 2.7879693665067774e-05
  15: 0.00039838616015114444
  16: 0.0
  18: 0.0020633612104619787
  20: 0.0016218197275284021
  30: 0.00017698551338515307
  31: 1.1065903904919655e-08
  32: 5.532951952459828e-09
  40: 0.1987493871255525
  44: 0.014717169549888214
  48: 0.14392298360372
  49: 0.0039048553037472045
  50: 0.1326861944777486
  51: 0.0723592229456223
  52: 0.002395131480328884
  60: 4.7084144280367186e-05
  70: 0.26681502148037506
  71: 0.006035012012626033
  72: 0.07814222006271769
  80: 0.002855498193863172
  81: 0.0006155958086189918
  99: 0.009923127583046915
  252: 0.001789309418528068
  253: 0.00012709999297008662
  254: 0.00016059776092534436
  255: 3.745553104802113e-05
  256: 0.0
  257: 0.00011351574470342043
  258: 0.00010157861367183268
  259: 4.3840131989471124e-05
# classes that are indistinguishable from single scan or inconsistent in
# ground truth are mapped to their closest equivalent
learning_map:
  0 : 0     # "unlabeled"
  1 : 0     # "outlier" mapped to "unlabeled" --------------------------mapped
  10: 1     # "car"
  11: 2     # "bicycle"
  13: 5     # "bus" mapped to "other-vehicle" --------------------------mapped
  15: 3     # "motorcycle"
  16: 5     # "on-rails" mapped to "other-vehicle" ---------------------mapped
  18: 4     # "truck"
  20: 5     # "other-vehicle"
  30: 6     # "person"
  31: 7     # "bicyclist"
  32: 8     # "motorcyclist"
  40: 9     # "road"
  44: 10    # "parking"
  48: 11    # "sidewalk"
  49: 12    # "other-ground"
  50: 13    # "building"
  51: 14    # "fence"
  52: 0     # "other-structure" mapped to "unlabeled" ------------------mapped
  60: 9     # "lane-marking" to "road" ---------------------------------mapped
  70: 15    # "vegetation"
  71: 16    # "trunk"
  72: 17    # "terrain"
  80: 18    # "pole"
  81: 19    # "traffic-sign"
  99: 0     # "other-object" to "unlabeled" ----------------------------mapped
  252: 1    # "moving-car" to "car" ------------------------------------mapped
  253: 7    # "moving-bicyclist" to "bicyclist" ------------------------mapped
  254: 6    # "moving-person" to "person" ------------------------------mapped
  255: 8    # "moving-motorcyclist" to "motorcyclist" ------------------mapped
  256: 5    # "moving-on-rails" mapped to "other-vehicle" --------------mapped
  257: 5    # "moving-bus" mapped to "other-vehicle" -------------------mapped
  258: 4    # "moving-truck" to "truck" --------------------------------mapped
  259: 5    # "moving-other"-vehicle to "other-vehicle" ----------------mapped
learning_map_inv: # inverse of previous map
  0: 0      # "unlabeled", and others ignored
  1: 10     # "car"
  2: 11     # "bicycle"
  3: 15     # "motorcycle"
  4: 18     # "truck"
  5: 20     # "other-vehicle"
  6: 30     # "person"
  7: 31     # "bicyclist"
  8: 32     # "motorcyclist"
  9: 40     # "road"
  10: 44    # "parking"
  11: 48    # "sidewalk"
  12: 49    # "other-ground"
  13: 50    # "building"
  14: 51    # "fence"
  15: 70    # "vegetation"
  16: 71    # "trunk"
  17: 72    # "terrain"
  18: 80    # "pole"
  19: 81    # "traffic-sign"
learning_ignore: # Ignore classes
  0: True      # "unlabeled", and others ignored
  1: False     # "car"
  2: False     # "bicycle"
  3: False     # "motorcycle"
  4: False     # "truck"
  5: False     # "other-vehicle"
  6: False     # "person"
  7: False     # "bicyclist"
  8: False     # "motorcyclist"
  9: False     # "road"
  10: False    # "parking"
  11: False    # "sidewalk"
  12: False    # "other-ground"
  13: False    # "building"
  14: False    # "fence"
  15: False    # "vegetation"
  16: False    # "trunk"
  17: False    # "terrain"
  18: False    # "pole"
  19: False    # "traffic-sign"
split: # sequence numbers
  train:
    - 0
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
    - 4
    - 5
    - 6
    - 7
    - 9
    - 10
  valid:
    - 8
  test:
    - 11
    - 12
    - 13
    - 14
    - 15
    - 16
    - 17
    - 18
    - 19
    - 20
    - 21
```

This is the code snippet that reads the .yaml file

```
  # Read labels
    if config.n_frames == 1:
        config_file = join(self.path, 'semantic-kitti.yaml')
    elif config.n_frames > 1:
        config_file = join(self.path, 'semantic-kitti-all.yaml')
    else:
        raise ValueError('number of frames has to be >= 1')

    with open(config_file, 'r') as stream:
        doc = yaml.safe_load(stream)
        all_labels = doc['labels']
        learning_map_inv = doc['learning_map_inv']
        learning_map = doc['learning_map']
        self.learning_map = np.zeros((np.max([k for k in learning_map.keys()]) + 1), dtype=np.int32)
        for k, v in learning_map.items():
            self.learning_map[k] = v

        self.learning_map_inv = np.zeros((np.max([k for k in learning_map_inv.keys()]) + 1), dtype=np.int32)
        for k, v in learning_map_inv.items():
            self.learning_map_inv[k] = v
```

I have not similar found the similar error to like mine. Please help me to solve this error Ü.

Comment: That file loads without problem in both `ruamel.yaml` and `PyYAML`  you don't have 66 columns on line 26, so you either are processing a different file or your process converts this correct YAML into something broken. Are you sure you copy and pasted `/content/Data/SemanticKitti/semantic-kitti.yaml` as your `.yaml` file?

Comment: I have not copy and pasted. I downloaded it from the source directly in my colab notebook using wget command.

Comment: I am talking about the file that your present here on SO not being what you have on your disk, not how you got the file on your disk. What you presented here doesn't throw that error, so until you correct that and gives something that throws that error on line 26, there is little we can do to help you.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I guess I have understood it wrong. I have copied and pasted it from here : https://github.com/PRBonn/semantic-kitti-api/blob/master/config/semantic-kitti.yaml.

Comment: And i have added the code snippet that reads the .yaml file in the main question

Comment: So you probably used copy and paste from github to get the file content here (skippig the first line), instead of copying that file content from the file `/content/Data/SemanticKitti/semantic-kitti.yaml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did use `wget` to get the file:

```
wget https://github.com/PRBonn/semantic-kitti-api/blob/master/config/semantic-kitti.yaml
```

and with the resulting file you get an error on line 26, column 66, as that line looks like:

```
<meta name="optimizely-datafile" content="{&quot;groups&quot;: [], &quot;environmentKey&
                                                             ^ this colon causes the error
```

The above doesn't look like YAML and that is because before you copy and paste the URL from github, you should first select the box [Raw] and then copy the URL:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PRBonn/semantic-kitti-api/master/config/semantic-kitti.yaml
```

Because of the `raw.` part a the start, you only get the **contents** of the file, not the **HTML page that
displays the content of the file** as in the first download.

And that file you can load with a YAML parser:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path

file_in = Path('semantic-kitti.yaml')
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='rt')
data = yaml.load(file_in.open())
lm = data['learning_map']
print('value:  ', lm[0])
print('comment:', lm.ca.items[0])
```

which gives:

```
value:   0
comment: [None, None, CommentToken('# "unlabeled"\n', line: 109, col: 12), None]
```

If you use `'safe'` instead of `'rt'` you won't get access to the comment but you will load about a magnitude
faster ( compared to PyYAML's `safe_load()` as well).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have thought using wget gives me the exact file from the github.